# Play audio file at fixed time in background in website

Tags: javascript, html, audio, alarm

I want to play a audio file at fixed time in background in website. Such as I want to play the audio/mp3 file at 15:20:30(Hour/Min/Sec). For this I have written a script also, but not working. The script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function sivamtime() {
now=new Date();
hour=now.getHours();
min=now.getMinutes();
sec=now.getSeconds();
var song = "1.mp3"; 
if (hour == 15 && min == 20 && sec == 30) { document.write("<embed src='" + song + "' hidden='true' border='0' autostart='true' loop='true'>") }
}
sivamtime()
// -->
</script>
```

I think my fault is in following line:

```
 if (hour == 15 && min == 20 && sec == 30) { document.write("<embed src='" + song + "' hidden='true' border='0' autostart='true' loop='true'>") }
}
```

Any help please.

Comment: BTW - we haven't needed to hide blocks of javascript with HTML comments (<!--) since 1998!

Comment: The function is only called once, rather than being on a repeated loop, so it only checks the time once, and if it is not correct (which it is not likely to be), then no sound is played.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function sivamtime() {
now=new Date();
hour=now.getHours();
min=now.getMinutes();
sec=now.getSeconds();
var song = "1.mp3"; 
if (hour == 15 && min == 20 && sec == 30) { document.write("<embed src='" + song + "' hidden='true' border='0' autostart='true' loop='true'>") }
}
setTimeOut("sivamtime()",1000);
// -->
</script>
```

This will make the function sivamtime() run every 1000 milliseconds - every second.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) library. It would make your code much easier and portable.